# proud to be & proud of being

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive, predicate-frames

I have the following two sentences which I would like to confirm the difference in meaning for.

- I am proud to be a nurse.
- I am proud of being a nurse.

I'm mainly wondering about the difference in the current status of the person saying such sentences.

The way I read it, 'I am proud to be a nurse' = I am a nurse now, and 'I am proud of being a nurse' = I was a nurse previously, but not anymore.

I'm looking for confirmation because of the use of 'being' in the second sentence and how that relates to time in this phrase.

Thank you.

Comment: The way I use these two sayings, and the way I understand their usage, is that 'I am proud to be' means 'I am privileged to be' or 'I am proud of having been appointed to be'; and 'I am proud of being' means 'I am proud of myself for being' or 'I am proud of what I have achieved'. The first emphasises the _privilege_ with the verbal infinitive. The second uses what I would call a genitive gerund to emphasis _one's own part_ in the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that there is a subtle difference between the two constructions, but I’m not so sure it’s necessarily what you’re thinking.  Or at least, I’m not sure that it ***always*** works that way.  I think it depends what kind of verb it is.

Consider these variants:

1. I am proud **to be** a nurse. (*ongoing*)
2. I am proud **of being** a nurse. (*???*)
3. I am proud **of having been** a nurse. (*no longer*)
4. I am proud **that I was** a nurse. (*clearly no longer*)
5. I am proud **to have been** a nurse. (*clearly no longer*)

Given those, I tend to view the second as being more like the first than like those following it here. I don’t necessarily see the second as being done with yet. This seems to remain true if the sentences are cast into the past tense.

5. She said that she was proud **to be** a nurse. (*ongoing*)
6. She said that she was proud **of being** a nurse. (*???*)
7. She said that she was proud **of having been** a nurse. (*no longer*)
8. She said that she was proud **that she was** a nurse. (*???*)
9. She said that she was proud **that she had been** a nurse. (*clearly no longer*)
10. She said that she was proud **to have been** a nurse. (*clearly no longer*)

In the last one, the past perfect aspect makes clear that at the time she was stating this, she wasn’t a nurse any longer.

The one thing that the *‑ing* version provides that the infinitive lacks is a sense of the continuous aspect. The continuous version emphasizes the ongoing process not the the simple state or condition. The difference may be more obvious with active verbs. Compare:

11. I’m proud **to call** you my friend. (*ongoing?*)
12. I’m proud **of calling** you my friend. (*???*)
13. I’m proud **that I called** you my friend. (*action complete*)
14. I’m proud **to have called** you my friend. (*action complete*)

This time around, the version with the continuous aspect (12) seems less like the one immediately before it (11) more like those following it (13 and 14).

It may be that there’s some sort of subtle restriction in using the continuous/progressive aspect with the verb here. If so, it might be 
the same ones that normally restricts the continuous aspect from being used
with abstract verbs or those related to possession or emotions.

15. I’m proud **to belong** someplace.
16. *I’m proud **of belonging** someplace.

That last one is at best questionable, and is probably ungrammatical.

This may be why active verbs feel different when used with the continuous aspect than other verbs do.

Answer (score 0):

I think both these sentences carry the same meaning & the first one is a bit closer to the purpose of the speaker.That is
1.The speaker is a nurse at present
and
2.She is proud of it.

Both these senses are clearer in the first sentence.

The second sentence is slightly farther from the intended meaning of the speaker.